# Use a directory to simulate a USB storage device? Or any other way to simulate a USB storage device?

Tags: linux, mount, usb

When it comes to CD's you have virtual CD software in which you load an .iso and it works like a CD-Rom. But when it comes to USB is there something similar?

Is it possible to use a directory to simulate a USB storage device?

Like mounting/unmounting that directory to simulate a plug/unplug of a USB storage device?

Purpose: to read(using an application) music or video files from a USB. The application reacts only when a USB is inserted/removed.

Or any other way could help. But files seem to be the linux way.
Or if there are no tools yet for this: how feasible it would be to write one?

Comment: Simulate it at what level? There huge difference between the extremes of what you could want: "oh, and want the files to appear and disappear to simulate unmounting/mounting it" vs "I want to simulate putting a logic analyzer on the USB data pins". Could you please tell us what you're trying to test/explore/etc. via this simulation?

Comment: @derobert reading music or video files from a USB. I updated my question.

Comment: Not sure why you deleted this---there is, I think, a perfectly good way to do this. In short, use a VM... Longer answer will have to wait until its voted no longer on hold.

Comment: I deleted it because it was put on hold and in the meanwhile I found something called qemu which may do the trick http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-doc.html#pcsys_005fusb

Comment: Yep, that'd be the virtualization I was about to point you to... Though I'd suggest using it through libvirt will probably be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix/Linux there are no CDs, USBs, FDs. There are just files and directories, so I don't quite understand what exactly is what you want to acomplish.

If you want to read music from a USB that music will be in a directory (usually udev will detect the insertion and according to the predefined rules some actions will be taken, like for instance mounting the device...) and it is just as simple as reading files from that directory. If you want to simulate that just place music files in a directory and you are ready to go.

If what you want is to detect when a USB is plugged in, then you should check udev rules. There you can set specific actions when a device is inserted but that should have nothing to do with your application which should only center in reading files....

Answer (score 0):

**udisks**

AFAIK the reactions to plugging/unplugging of a USB storage device are handled by udisks (http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/). So you would have to configure (udev and) udisks for a simple storage area the same way they are configured for USB. Unfortunately I cannot tell you how to do that. But the application should not care about the storage being USB but just about being notified accordingly.